# Does Puri Sankaracharya or other teachers say what aspects of the British Raj were divine and based on Manusmriti?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, manu-smriti

Hindi video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9eI-hC7Aqs around 8:05

> Their (British) rule had its glaring negativities thanks to their mental devilry, but whatever trace of divinity it had was due to Manusmriti.

So, what aspects of the Raj were divine and how were they in accord with Manusmriti?  Has the Sankaracharya or other teachers explained this in more detail?

Comment: He is saying that "whatever **trace** of divinity it had was due to Manusmriti."

Comment: Not sure how to answer this using any references. It would be a simple yes or no answer restating the same thing he said in the video. Better to rephrase the question so it can be answered using some references.

Comment: His views are passé, Overrall his thoughts are irrelevant in this grim age of kali.

Comment: @KrsnaDasa - they're only irrelevant to those who don't mind suffering. Can't blame the Yuga for people's faults.

Comment: Not so, for every yuga the particular proscription is recommended in the sastra, and Govardhan mutt swami completely Misses it to the point of being a complete passé @mar

Comment: @KrsnaDasa - yes, every yuga has a different smriti. but if that were followed strictly child marriage would have been stopped 5000 years ago when kali yug began. nowadays it has become fashion to postpone beyond legal age, leading to all sorts of instabilities in society.